# How to create CURL command for POST request - {"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Empty scope (either the client or the user is not allowed

Tags: curl

I am a beginner with cURL commands. I was able to successfully get the response for the following URL from the Mozilla REST Client:

```
http://localhost:8080/demo.rest.springsecurity.oauth2.0.authentication/oauth/token?username=user1&password=user1&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&grant_type
=password&scope=read,write,trust
```

[image]

But when I was trying same using CURL command I see error. I created CURL command like below. What needs to be corrected here?

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/demo.rest.springsecurity.oauth2.0.authentication/oauth/token -H “Accept: application/json” -d 
"username=user1&password=user1&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&grant_type=password"
```

This gives me below error:

```
C:\>curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/demo.rest.springsecurity.oauth2.0.authentication/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "username=user1&password=user1&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&grant_type=password"
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Empty scope (either the client or the user is not allowed the requested scopes)"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

### Edit

As per response from Yuvika, I got

```
C:\>curl -vvv -X POST "http://localhost:8080/demo.rest.springsecurity.oauth2.0.authentication/oauth/token?username=user1&password=user1&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&grant_type=password&scope=read,write,trust"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /demo.rest.springsecurity.oauth2.0.authentication/oauth/token?username=user1&password=user1&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&grant_type=password&scope=read,write,trust HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 05:36:08 GMT
<
    {"access_token":"ed788e8c-e504-4307-b43e-558914f85bf3","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"3e7e7dca-0db3-4423-a49d-
842783fd9632","expires_in":299999,"scope":"read,write,trust"}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: Shoudnt your -d Parameter be json formatted?

Comment: Hannes - Are you saying like below?
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/demo.rest.springsecurity.oauth2.0.authentication/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "{username:user1,password:user1,client_id:client1,client_secret:client1,grant_type:password}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `-d`, the parameter are sent as a request body and not part of the request URL. Does your application support this? If not, this should work  `curl -vvv -X POST "http://localhost:8080/demo.rest.springsecurity.oauth2.0.authentication/oauth/token?username=user1&password=user1&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&grant_type =password&scope=read,write,trust"`